# No veo el ViewController inicial en appDelegate swift

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller

Estoy acostumbrado a definir en el método **application** del **appDelegate** el viewController con el que la aplicación inicia, por ejemplo:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //inicializar la aplicación
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let mainVC = MainVC()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)

    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Sin embargo, me he encontrado con proyectos (en cocoapods sobre todo) que no tienen nada definido en el appDelegate y la aplicación inicia en un Controller determinado, aun cuando existe mas de uno en la misma ruta.

¿Cuál es la regla de ejecución del ViewController default? ¿Hay algo dentro del controlador que estoy omitiendo y que permite ejecutarse como controlador default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes un storyboard definido, le puedes indicar cual es el viewcontroller inicial. En el proyecto tienes definido cual es el storyboard inicial. Asi que iOS sabe cual es el storyboard que tiene que arrancar y sabe que controlador tiene que iniciar